# Gadfly uses reserved words in python. How does it do that?

Tags: python

I was looking through the source code of [Gadfly](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gadfly/), a python-based SQL database, and I noticed in one of the files that various methods use the `as` reserved word:

Code excerpt from `bindings.py`:

```
def trl1as(l,c):
    [name, as, alias] = l
    return [(name, alias)]

....

def selectname(list, context):
    [exp, as, alias] = list
    return (exp, alias)
```

As expected, when I tried to import this file into the python shell, it gave me a syntax error.

```
>>> from gadfly import bindings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "gadfly/bindings.py", line 64
    [create, view, name, namelist, as, selection] = l
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How does it get away with using reserved words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not allow you to make a variable that has the same name as one of the keywords.  Doing so is illegal in every version and will always raise a `SyntaxError`.

Thus, your script must have been written before `as` was made a keyword.  This happened in version 2.5. As proof, notice how `as` is listed among the [Python 2.5 keywords](http://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html), but not the [Python 2.4 keywords](http://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/keywords.html).